# What's the best ViewModel javascript files organization, working with asp.net MVC3 and knockout js library?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, knockout.js

I am thinking to add the specific javascript ViewModel files into each view folder, but it seems asp.net MVC doesn't allow it and I should do some tweaks on the web.config. Other options I've found online is to put the javascript into partial views, or into the /Scripts folder.

Which are your recommendation and thoughts ?

Comment: What makes you think MVC doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in the scripts folder and have a sub folder structure for js with controller, model and viewModel folders in the script folder

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using proposed folder structure and creating some naming conventions? MVC folder structure is kind of convention. If you follow that convention, then other developers will find it easier to understand your project.

I would suggest creating a naming convention for your java script files. For example, I might have a view for displaying customer details - `Customer\Details.cshtml`. I would then add java script file into default Scripts folder and name it `MyProject.Customer.Details.js` Also I might be wrong, but I guess that you are referring to a view, rather then a view model.